# Arrays with Reduce and Filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, logic

i have a question here. I'm learning JavaScript and I'm new here on StackOverflow. So, if I have an

```
Array = [ 7, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7]
```

How can i show the values of this array greater than the average of these numbers using the Filter and Reduction functions? I have done this

```
const values = [5, 6, 10, 4, 3, 7, 1]


function averageValues(v) {
    let sum = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
        sum += v[i]
    }
    return sum/v.length
}

const average = averageValues(values)
console.log('Average = ' + average)

console.log(values.filter(function(v){
    return v > average
}))
```

Comment: Looks good. I'd keep it like that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce shows exactly how to compute sum...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use reduce to find the average:

```
const average = values.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur) / values.length
```

Then you can run run your other function:

```
values.filter(v => v > average)
```

Comment: another way to compute avg `const average = values.reduce((avg,value,index) => avg+(value-avg)/(index+1))` for situations where you don't have/want to store your Array in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
const values = [5, 6, 10, 4, 3, 7, 1]

const sum = values.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
}, 0);

const average = sum / values.length + 1

console.log(average)
```

In this reduce function you have 2 parameters. The first one **a** is the current value. The second one **b** the accumulator.

Average function with reduce work like this:

At the first iteration:

- accumulator (a) is equal to 0
- current value (b) is equal to 5 (first index of the array)
- 5 is returned

At the second iteration:

- accumulator (a) is equal 5 (it's the result of the previous
  operation)
- current value (b) is equal 6 (second index of the array)
- 11 is returned (a + b)

And so on ...

> If you look more closer, at the end (after curly brackets) you have a
>   zero. It's the Initial value, not an obligation to specify if you
>   decide to start to count from 0. But if you want you can specify 8
>   then on the first loop accumulator value is equal to 8.

In this case first iteration is equal to:

- accumulator (a) is equal 8
- current value (b) is equal 5
- 13 is returned

At the end sum will be equal to 44.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to use .reduce() in this assignment, I would do the following:

```
const values = [5, 6, 10, 4, 3, 7, 1];


function averageValues(v) {
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    return v.reduce(reducer)/v.length;
}

const average = averageValues(values);
console.log('Average = ' + average);

console.log(values.filter(v => v > average))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like this:

```js
const arr = [7, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7];
const average = arr.reduce((acc, v) => (acc + v), 0) / arr.length;
console.log(average);

const greaterThan = arr.filter(v => v > average);
console.log(greaterThan);
```

Hope this helps,